# Simple questions regarding using a Linux driver

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, driver

I am writing a simple program in C++ that interfaces with the QCA7000 chip. There is already a driver available on Linux for using this chip. I have a couple of questions regarding the use of the driver.

1. For loading the driver into the kernel, what are the cases for when I should use init_module and finit_module()?
2. I found the source code for the driver and there are a number of functions available for the driver ([GitHub source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/ethernet/qualcomm)). After I initialize the module, how do I access the functions? Or are there standard Linux kernel functions that I am suppose to call that will interface to the driver for me? I have been looking for awhile on this matter and it is unclear how I utilize the driver in an application.

Comment: But the second part is what you should choose. Write a mock up of the user space program, and so check what interface is more relevant to you: creating a character device? a block device? using IOCL? files in sys? own system call?

Comment: Yes so I have the compiled driver installed in the location that it should be. It is called qca_7k_common. As for the other part, I am not sure what you mean

Comment: Kernel is just a provider of services. You must have a user space program (so a normal program) which will use the services of the kernel. So you should check how you will implement such things in a program. Now I googled, and I see that it seems either a network or a UART device. So possibly you can use existing driver and just open the pty of that driver. You just use C++ file operation (read and write) to exchange data.

Comment: That is correct, however, in the application I am going to use the SPI for faster data transfers. For that, I will need the driver

Comment: So, the **actual** question is "How to use SPI in user space code", isn't it?

Comment: Well no becuase I am not directly programming SPI. There is already a driver for the chip that communicates over SPI in Linux. The question still stands since I want to use the driver.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi So are you saying that when I load the module in the C++ program, I can write/read to it from the pty? I am creating a program that will communicate with the device to send and receive data, that is pretty much it

Comment: You cannot load a kernel module from a C++ program. kernel is kernel and only kernel can load modules (in a different memory space, permissions, etc.). kernel modules cannot be written in C++. So you may just tell the kernel to install a module. And then you need a kernel interface (so it seems SPI in your case) to communicate between the program and the kernel. Check a program with similar needs (and so similar architecture), and get inspired from it (for sure you are not the only one with similar problem). Note: hardware (or its task) do not matter for such inspiration, just a SPI program

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi, huh? The kernel does not load the drivers, which are external modules, (maybe it will be a surprise to you), user space does. It very well may be a C++ program, but traditionally we use `kmod` tools for that, which are written in C.

Comment: As far as I understand, the chip is a simple Ethernet one, so in Linux we are using so called *netlink* ABI. This is used by many network related tools, such as `iproute2`. I'm not sure what exactly you need from that driver that standard tools can't provide to you. (@Tsyvarev, perhaps this clarifies the needs by OP)